# Unterschied zwischen „herunterfallen“, „hinabfallen“ usw.

Tags: word-choice

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *herunterfallen* und *hinabfallen*? Und was sagt man normalerweise in Bezug auf Schnee?

> Der Schnee fällt über die Straßen herunter.
>   Der Schnee fällt über/auf die Straßen hinab.

Comment: Schnee fällt normalerweise *auf*, nicht *über*, v.a. nicht mit hin-/herab.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ob *her-* oder *hin-* kommt auf den Standort des Beobachters und die Bewegung des beobachteten Objekts an:

**hin-** = **weg vom** Beobachter (Eselsbrücke: da geht es *dahin*)
**her-** = **auf** den Beobachter **zu**

Steht man oben, fällt etwas *hinab* (weg vom Beobachter), 
steht man unten, fällt etwas *herunter* oder *herab* (auf den Beobachter zu).

Das gilt ebenso für *hinauf* (Beobachter steht unten) und *herauf* (Beobachter ist schon oben).

Für die Passanten auf der Straße fällt der Schnee *herab*.

Ganz deutlich wird der Mechanismus, wenn man aus einer höheren Etage blickt: Der Schnee fällt vom Himmel *herab* auf die Straße *hinunter*.

Comment: Ich habe mich immer gefragt, ob es etwas über die Sicht von Microsoft Windows-Entwicklern auf die Benutzer aussagt, dass man Windows HERunterfahren (und nicht etwas HINunterfahren) muss. +1 für den letzten Satz, aber für den Unterschied zwischen "-ab" und "-unter" würde mir jetzt auch keine gute Erklärung einfallen....